# Why I can't speed up a speed up transaction in MetaMask?

Tags: transactions, metamask, pending-transactions, cancel-transaction

I was working MetaMask:

- Send (do) a transaction
- two buttons for controlling the transaction appear `Cancel` & `Speed up`
- Speed up transaction

Only cancel button is there and I can't speed up the transaction again.

But when I cancel a transaction, `Speed up cancellation` appears and I can do this operation as many times I want.

So my question is "Why I can't `speed up` a `speed up transaction` in MetaMask?"

Another question:

- Send (do) a transaction
- two buttons for controlling the transaction appear `Cancel` & `Speed up`
- Speed up the transaction
- Cancel the transaction

No buttons are showing, So antoher question is "Why I can't do a `Speed up cancellation` in this case?"